# Javac doesn't exist

Tags: javac

Well i tried to start with react native when suddenly i got an error that java compiler couldn't be found. So i searched and find something about java_home which i fixed but still the compiler isnt found. After testing in the cmd prompt javac -version couldn't it recognise any javac. Then i looked in the bin folder in java jre and realised that the javac doesnt even exist. Is this some kind of bug or should i reinstall it or something.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h75lF.png)

Comment: sorry the image was uploaded wrong but its in that link

Comment: You need to install JDK

Comment: i think JDK is installed aswell, the folder is right under the JRE folder, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2

Comment: tried installing the jdk package but cmd can still not find javac

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `jdk` as `jre` is for executing already compiled code. But for a whole new compilation you require a jdk that is development tools of java development toolkit. As `javac.exe` is a part of jdk not jre.

Comment: where can i get the javac.jar file then? just from their website

Comment: how you had installed the `JRE` ? or else reinstall it

Comment: ok i just tried reinstall the whole java, it uninstalled the old ones and installed the new. C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191 exist but javac still doesn't exist

Comment: you need a jdk ill reedit my answer

Comment: i think i already has jdk, the jdk folder is under the jre C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2

Answer (score 0):

The image shows a JRE. javac is java compiler, if it's required you need to install JDK.

Comment: i have jdk folder under the JRE and it has javac in the bin folder there, should i re locate it to the jre/bin folder?

Comment: no check the bin of jdk is javac there ?

Comment: use cmd first `cd \filepath..`  to your java file then `set path =..jdk\bin ` then `javac filename.java `

Comment: wait so you mean ..jdk\bin\javac filename.java? sorry its first time im around on these parts